# I want to display image dynamically in Tkinter using Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to be able to display photos dynamically in Tkinter I have one button that will find the paths to the photos I want to display and as I add photos I want them to be displayed at the top of the canvas

I have already tried going through a for loop of the array after I upload the photos but that doesn't seem to do what I want, and now I am trying to iterate with a while loop but that doesn't work. I am kind of at a loss now. Below is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as tkfd
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time

photo_name_list = []

def find_photos():
    photo = tkfd.askopenfile()
    photo_name_list.append(photo.name)

window = tk.Tk()
#creates the canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = WINDOW_WIDTH,
                   height = WINDOW_HEIGHT, bg="green")
canvas.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(canvas, text="Click me to add 5 photos of yourself",
               height = 5, width = 30, command = find_photos)
canvas.create_window(WINDOW_WIDTH//3, WINDOW_HEIGHT//3, window = b1)
while True:
    if len(photo_name_list) > 0:
        for image in photo_name_list:
            img = Image.open(image)
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            tk.Label(window, image=tkimage).pack()
    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(1/60)






window.mainloop()
```

So as you can see in the code I have one button that does that takes the path to an image as a string and appends it to the list. I want to display photos as they are appended.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is the program crashing? Is it showing the wrong image?

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as tkfd
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
WINDOW_WIDTH = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500
phat_list = []
images_reference_list = []

def find_photos():
    photo = tkfd.askopenfile()

    file_path = photo.name
    img = Image.open(file_path)
    photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    tk.Label(window, image=photo_image).pack(side=tk.TOP)
    images_reference_list.append(photo_image)

    phat_list.append(file_path)

window = tk.Tk()
#creates the canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = WINDOW_WIDTH,
                   height = WINDOW_HEIGHT, bg="green")
canvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

b1 = tk.Button(canvas, text="Click me to add 5 photos of yourself",
               height = 5, width = 30, command = find_photos)
canvas.create_window(WINDOW_WIDTH//3, WINDOW_HEIGHT//3, window = b1)


window.mainloop()
```

I've added the code lines that display the photo inside the function  `find_photos()`.

The `while` statement was causing some troubles i assume, you have always to check if the while will ever end for have a working code

and if you want to display an image you have always to keep a solid reference of it , the best way is to add it into a list